# How do I disconnect a garbage disposal wall switch?

Tags: wiring, garbage-disposal

How do I eliminate a wall switch to the garbage disposal?

I’m getting new countertops, sink and backsplash.The new garbage disposal will be operated with an air switch.

When tiling the backsplash, can I have the wall switch for the garbage disposal removed and have the wall patched?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on  the wiring in the switch box. More than likely there are two (*or more*) sets of wires coming into the box and disconnecting and removing the switch still   means it is junction box. By code; a junction box **Can not be covered or buried in the wall.**  *The box must have a cover that can be removed for access to the wires.*

You would have to   remove both/all wires **all the way back to their source**, which would  mean opening walls because the wires are stapled to the studs (*unless they are run in conduit*) and they may originate some distance from the box.

The air switch Eliminates the need for the wall switch but the power to the outlet for the disposal is still needed, and it is probably coming from the box that houses the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This makes sense.